# Postasync works with UWP but breaks on android project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

The below code  is used from a cross-platform solution.

```
 var auth = new SigninModel
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password
            };

var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auth), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await Client.PostAsync("http://localhost:54019/api/AuthenticationApi/Login", stringContent);
```

Below is my webservice code

```
 [System.Web.Http.Route("api/AuthenticationApi/Login/")]
 [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]   
  public DBResult Login(AuthenticationModel model)
        {
         return new DBResult {}
        }
```

Comment: What breaks? Do you get any error? If yes, what is it? What have you tried? I am sorry, but this question has too little information for us to go on and does not show any effort on your part. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Using `localhost` on the Android device/emulator would be addressing itself (unless you have port-forwarded it via `adb`), not your web service. Use an hostname/ip that is externally accessible, test it via the browser on the device/emulator .

Comment: @Gerald, I dont get anything except this "An unhandled exception occured."

Comment: Still, there is a message associated to this exception. If it is not very clear, check your output logs. Also as @SushiHangover mentioned, you probably should not use `localhost` as an address. See what happens if you paste the URL in your emulator browser and determine if it shows you something that you would expect or triggers a breakpoint in your server or something like that. Anything to determine whether the request ever reaches the server.

Comment: Thanks guys this helped me: https://forums.asp.net/t/1881866.aspx?VS2012+IISExpress+localhost+ipaddress